# What means when "you're not sold on 1-3"?

Tags: meaning

I found a funny pic on the internet with reasons to date me, but i don t get this line: " if you re not sold on 1-3, look at my butt"

Answer (score 3):

This is from a dating site called POF.com.  (POF stands for "plenty of fish," which refers to the saying, "If you don't want me, there's plenty of fish in the sea."  In other words, you can go, there are more opportunities for me out there."  One of the [people](http://www.pof.com/member97722545.htm) on POF posted some pictures of herself and this list:

> *REASONS TO DATE ME:
>   1. I can COOK
>   2. I'm funny
>   3. We can lay in bed & eat pizza & watch Netflix.....NAKED
>  
>   4. If you're not sold on 1-3, look at my butt. 
>   5. If that doesn't work, you like men....

"Sold" means convinced here.  Item 4 means, that if a man is not convinced by her given reasons 1 to 3 to ask her for a date -- her cooking or her sense of humor or the way she watches movies -- then he should take a look at her pleasing figure, especially her shapely behind.

(And if No. 4 doesn't do it, then the man must be gay.)

Answer (score 1):

*To be sold* in this instance is an idiomatic expression meaning *to be convinced by*.

"I saw a film last night, I was sold in the first five minutes", meaning the first five minutes were so gripping that you had to watch the rest of the film.

So here you a list of reasons why you should date someone. Nos 1-3 should be enough to convince you (to sell it to you), but if they aren't then 'look at my butt' is the 4th reason which will put it beyond any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

It usually means "if you're not yet fully convinced".